# solcx compile_files Key error

Tags: solidity, web3.py, solc, python

I am using python package py-solc-x for compiling the smart contract.

```
os.path.abspath("D:/new.sol")
```

Gives path where my test contract exits. `'D:\\new.sol'`

Then i  use compile_files to compile the contract `compile_files([os.path.abspath("D:/new.sol")])` , it gives KeyError.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Muvi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\solcx\main.py", line 137, in compile_files
    contracts = _parse_compiler_output(stdoutdata)
  File "C:\Users\Muvi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\solcx\main.py", line 73, in _parse_compiler_output
    data['ast'] = sources[source.split(':')[0]]['AST']
KeyError: 'D'
```

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you've found a bug in py-solc-x.

As far as I can tell, the issue is specific to Windows paths that are given absolutely. I was able to compile successfully by using a path that did not include a drive letter.

I am the maintainer of py-solc-x, I will push a new version with a fix as soon as possible. In the short term try running the script from the same folder as `new.sol` and compile with `solcx.compile_files(['new.sol'])`.

Comment: omg.. Thanks a lot sir.. I'm very pleased that i am able to contribute something.  ☺

Comment: I've just pushed a new version to pypi (v0.4.1) - this issue should now be fixed.